# How to change NSString value while debugging in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, debugging

When I'm stopped at a break point in Xcode, I can see the value of NSString variables. How can I change them? I can change int or double variables, but not NSString.

Comment: in 1987 we could easily use the equivalent of Xcode's "Edit Value..." in all the *real* debuggers. Now we are relegated to writing debugger code... Back to the Future...

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You can do this in the debug console. Say you have `NSString* myVar`. In the console, after `(gdb)`, type `set myVar = @"My new string"`. If you are using `(lldb)`, then use the equivalent expression `expr myVar = @"My new string"` instead.

This may not show up correctly in the variables panel, but you can verify the value by entering `po myVar` into the console. Your code should pick up the new value.

For some great info about using `expr`, check out [this StackOverflow post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907387/how-to-change-variables-value-while-debugging-with-llvm-in-xcode)

Comment: This doesn't work for me in XCode 4.3.1 using (lldb). I get errors about "reference to 'id' is ambiguous" and "1 errors parsing expression".

Comment: You are hitting a variation of a known bug in XCode 4.3.x. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515630/lldb-fails-to-print-variable-values-with-error-reference-to-id-is-ambiguous). According to the answer, this is resolved in XCode 4.4

Comment: Using expr whateverVariable = @"55fc633a22570e2b7e00003b"        worked for me.

Comment: Its about the same amount of work to put: NSString * whateverVariable = @"55fc633a22570e2b7e00003b"; in the code itself. Sigh

Answer (score 8):

You can but you have to call code from the debugger command prompt.
For example, say you have a breakpoint fire off right after this line:

```
NSString *myString = @"My current string";
```

Then at the (gdb) prompt type:

```
call myString = @"My new string"
```

You can `po myString` before changing the string and after you change it to verify that it has changed.

Another example:  Say you wanted to change a view controller's title.  You can use the setter.  *Note: dot notation is not supported at the debugger command line.  For example let the view load and then set a breakpoint somewhere during the lifetime of your view controller.  Then do this:

```
call (id)[self setTitle:@"New Title"]
```

Continue running the program and you should see your view controller's title update.

Comment: my answer is old. You can actually do this now: **po myString = @"my_new_string"** and **po self.title = @"New Title"**

Answer (score 2):

For NSError I am using this:

```
(lldb) expression aTempError = (NSError*)[[NSError alloc] initWithDomain:@"MANO" code:1 userInfo:nil]
```

Answer (score 1):

(https://stackoverflow.com/users/1202867/n8tr) n8tr's comment from above shows how to do it. You just precede your assignment with "po " like so: po myString = @"my_new_string" and po self.title = @"New Title".