# How to print out a property's contents using Xcode debugger?

Tags: ios, xcode, gdb, lldb

I'm writing an iOS app and I need help using the built-in Xcode debugger.  Suppose I have an object called `HomeViewController` that has three properties

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL finished;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *myArray;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *myName;

@synthesize finished = _finished, myArray = _myArray, myName = _myName;
```

Suppose I have a breakpoint in this class.  How would I view the contents of these properties? I've tried things such as `po myName`, `print myName` and `print [self myName]` but I can't figure out how to do this.  I've tried using LLDB but I keep getting the same error that this person encountered ([lldb fails to print variable values with "error: reference to 'id' is ambiguous"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515630/lldb-fails-to-print-variable-values-with-error-reference-to-id-is-ambiguous)) .  The accepted answer to this question was, LLDB is broken and that I should just use GDB; however, I refuse to accept that something so fundamental is broken.

Nevertheless, I've also tried using GDB with similar commands as above; however, I can't get GDB to work either.  Help please

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Once you place a breakpoint, run, and the program stops at the breakpoint, hover your cursor over the variable/value you want to see like this:

[image]

You could also place an `NSLog(@"%@", yourLabel.text);` to view the contents of that label/other object type.

One other option is to run GDB in the console like this:

```
gdb
attach <your process name>
```

And then use the `po` (print-object) command to view the value of a variable like this:

```
po variableName
```

To view the value of primitive types (`int`, `float`, `long`, `double`, `char`, etc.), you can just use the `print` command while running GDB in the console like this:

```
print yourPrimitiveVariable
```

Hope this helps!

EDIT:

With the `po` command, you can print out the value of an object using both the property name (`self.myProperty`) or the ivar name (possibly `_myProperty`). I demonstrate this here:

[image]

Comment: So, if I use po do I have to print the ivar or is there a way to print using the property's name? (sometimes my properties have different names than their corresponding variable)

Comment: @Nosrettap Try using the property name and if it doesn't work, I'll try to find a workaround.

Comment: @Nosrettap - I tested out the `po` and `print` commands and it looks like it works fine with both the property and ivar name. See my update...

Comment: Whenever I try to do this I keep getting the following error: `error: error: reference to 'id' is ambiguous
note: candidate found by name lookup is 'id'
note: candidate found by name lookup is 'id'
error: 1 errors parsing expression`

Answer (score 4):

Try with following expression in debug area to print object,

```
p self.view.bounds.size.width
```

or use,

```
po self.view
```

p - Print is only uses to print normal/simple values
while,
po - Print Object works same as NSLog to print value of an object