# Viewing NSData contents in Xcode (Swift)

Tags: xcode, swift

I'm trying to see the contents of an NSData variable `data` in the Xcode debugger.  This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11531353/viewing-nsdata-contents-in-xcode) asks the same thing but regards to an Objective C pointer to an NSData variable.  How can you do this with a Swift NSData variable?

Note in this case the data is a String.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to see the string representation of your NSData variable you can use the following code in the debugger

```
po NSString(data: yourData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

Comment: Worked perfectly.  Thank you.

Comment: Current syntax is `po String(data: xmlData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)`.