# Xcode crashes when debbuging

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode7, carthage

I have big problem with my Xcode and the problem is that I can't debbuging some of my projects. When I tried to show values or print them in console window (with `po` command) Xcode crashed.

I've seen many questions/topics about this and some suggested solutions but nothing help me. For example what I've tried:

- Delete derived data
- Delete all breakpoints
- Different versions of Xcode (I have this problem from Xcode 7.0)
- CLANG_ENABLE_MODULE_DEBUGGING set to false
- Restarting Xcode and OS
- Reinstalling Xcode
- Reinstall Mac OS X (with keeping data)

I am using carthage and I tried command:

```
carthage update --platform ios --no-use-binaries
```

Nothing help so far. I guess the real problem is some bug in Xcode or something but I can't wait Apple to fix this. Is there anyway how can I fix it myself? I can't stop using debbuger.

Here is more info from Xcode crash window:

[First info lines](http://pastebin.com/raw/t8s6tkgA)

[Thread which crash](http://pastebin.com/raw/67KF8Q1T)

Thanks for any help

Comment: Why not just reinstall Xcode?

Comment: I tried it. It didn't help.

Comment: Well, I don't know that much about Xcode but if you have multiple projects that do that maybe you could find a pattern, they use a specific library or a specific setting or version of swift which cause the crash. If you find the problem maybe there is a way around it.

Comment: [File a radar!](https://bugreport.apple.com)

Comment: @LiborZapletal I had this issue. Upgrade your Xcode to 7.2.1 using Mac Store. They fixed it.

Comment: I have 7.2 version. I'll try it update to 7.2.1 and I try beta version of 7.3 and I hope you are right.

Answer (score -3):

I'm not use "**po command**" when debug, I'm usually use **NSLog** to see value.

You can read at here: [How to print out a property's contents using Xcode debugger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11513283/how-to-print-out-a-propertys-contents-using-xcode-debugger)

Regard!