# How to get the current displaying UIViewController not in AppDelegate?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, swift3

I'm trying to get the currently display `UIViewController` that is not in the AppDelegate, but it seems to always get the initial top `UIViewController`, and not the present one.

The following code in AppDelegate DOES get the current `UIViewController` present, but this same function does not work when I use it in any one of my View Controllers:

```
func getTopViewController() -> UIViewController
{
    var topViewController = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate!.window!!.rootViewController!
    while (topViewController.presentedViewController != nil) {
        topViewController = topViewController.presentedViewController!
    }
    return topViewController
}
```

The above code was provided as an answer in a similar question:
[Get the current displaying UIViewController on the screen in AppDelegate.m](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40760970/2373410)

No matter how deep down I segue to, I can only retrieve the first-most View Controller.

How can I get the current presenting `UIViewController`?

FYI: I'm **NOT** using a `UINavigationController`, just regular `UIViewController` classes.

Comment: Are you using a navigation controller ?

Comment: @Lefteris: updated...thanks

Answer (score 18):

I do not like using this but sometimes it is necessary.

```
static func getTopViewController() -> UIViewController {

    var viewController = UIViewController()

    if let vc =  UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.rootViewController {

        viewController = vc
        var presented = vc

        while let top = presented.presentedViewController {
            presented = top
            viewController = top
        }
    }

    return viewController
}
```

**EDIT:

Here is an improved version, it will always get top most view controller

```
static var top: UIViewController? {
    get {
        return topViewController()
    }
}

static var root: UIViewController? {
    get {
        return UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.rootViewController
    }
}

static func topViewController(from viewController: UIViewController? = UIViewController.root) -> UIViewController? {
    if let tabBarViewController = viewController as? UITabBarController {
        return topViewController(from: tabBarViewController.selectedViewController)
    } else if let navigationController = viewController as? UINavigationController {
        return topViewController(from: navigationController.visibleViewController)
    } else if let presentedViewController = viewController?.presentedViewController {
        return topViewController(from: presentedViewController)
    } else {
        return viewController
    }
}
```

Comment: this does not work, I put this in VC2 but it still grabs the top-most VC, i.e. VC1 even though I segued from VC1->VC2

Comment: Did you try using debug and "po" to see how you can get VC2?

Comment: Enter debug mode in xcode, and you have po ( print object) command in xcode terminal. You can print your current vc and found out how to get to top presented.

Comment: This is example how to use po 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/11513877/5324438

Comment: I know it's been like 4 months but could you explain what your code does. It works perfect for me. But I just want to understand how it achieves.

Comment: @user30646 I added improved version of this, it just enumerates trough view controller until it finds last one.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the same idea in one function:

```
func topController(_ parent:UIViewController? = nil) -> UIViewController {
    if let vc = parent {
        if let tab = vc as? UITabBarController, let selected = tab.selectedViewController {
            return topController(selected)
        } else if let nav = vc as? UINavigationController, let top = nav.topViewController {
            return topController(top)
        } else if let presented = vc.presentedViewController {
            return topController(presented)
        } else {
            return vc
        }
    } else {
        return topController(UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.rootViewController!)
    }
}
```

works for me in Swift 4 project