# How to change variables value while debugging with LLDB in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, debugging, lldb

In Xcode, GDB allows you to change local variables while debugging (see [how to change NSString value while debugging in XCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858159/how-to-change-nsstring-value-while-debugging-in-xcode)). Does LLDB offer a similar functionality? If so, how can we use it?

Comment: Make sure to see [Advanced debugging in iOS](https://jayeshkawli.ghost.io/advanced-debugging-in-ios/). It's awesome

Comment: I'm trying to set an objects property, which works if the string length is between 0-15 characters. Setting a string of 16 or more characters is accepted, but when i print it back, it shows me a nonsense string:
po myObj.someString = "1234567890123456", which works, but when i print I get (String? $R68 = "\0\0\0\0@\a\u{1}\c{5}\0\0\0\0\0\0\"

Answer (score 301, accepted):

```
expr myString = @"Foo"
```

> (lldb) help expr
>   Evaluate a C/ObjC/C++ expression in the current
>   program context, using    variables currently in scope.  This command
>   takes 'raw' input (no need to    quote stuff).
>
> Syntax: expression  --
>
> Command Options Usage:   expression [-f ] [-G ]
>   [-d ] [-u ] --    expression [-o] [-d
>   ] [-u ] --    expression
>
> ```
>    -G <gdb-format>  ( --gdb-format <gdb-format> )
>         Specify a format using a GDB format specifier string.
>
>    -d <boolean>  ( --dynamic-value <boolean> )
>         Upcast the value resulting from the expression to its dynamic type
>         if available.
>
>    -f <format>  ( --format <format> )
>         Specify a format to be used for display.
>
>    -o  ( --object-description )
>         Print the object description of the value resulting from the
>         expression.
>
>    -u <boolean>  ( --unwind-on-error <boolean> )
>         Clean up program state if the expression causes a crash, breakpoint
>         hit or signal.
> ```
>
> Examples:
>
> expr my_struct->a = my_array[3]
>        expr -f bin -- (index * 8) + 5
>   expr char c[] = "foo"; c[0]
>
> IMPORTANT NOTE:  Because this command takes 'raw' input, if you use any    command options you must use ' -- ' between the end of the
>   command options    and the beginning of the raw input.
>
> 'expr' is an abbreviation for 'expression'

Comment: Indeed, thanks! One more little question: I'm doing this to try to change the text of a UILabel: `'expr myLabel.text = @"hello!"` but I get an `error: property 'text' not found on object of type 'UILabel *'`... Any thoughts?

Comment: `expr (void)[label setText:@"Foo"]` should do it. Dot-Syntax usually won't work in the debugger. lldb probably interprets it as you wanted to access a member of a c-struct, but I'm not sure if this is the reason it won't work. Dot-Syntax doesn't work for `po` either. instead of `po label.text` you have to use `po [label text]`

Comment: Actually, lldb handles dot syntax much better than gdb. gdb just assumes you're treating it like a C-struct, which fails. lldb will correctly access properties, but only if they're actually declared with `@property`.

Comment: You can also use `p` as a shortcut for `expr`. Example: `(lldb) p url = @"http://google.com"`

Comment: I found that while using LLVM and Swift, if I had a method parameter that was passed and I tried to change it, the value would change, but the code would not recognize the change (ie I changed a Bool from false to true). I had to change the value in LLVM before the method call and then the code would see the change.

Comment: You can also use `e` as a shortcut for `expr`. BTW, `p` is an alias for print which is an alias for `expr --` (just evalue raw input, no flags) `expr -o -- [object]` or `po` generally gives you more useful output for objects though.

Answer (score 23):

The following stuff works for me.
I am using Xcode 8.

If you want to set some variable (for example a "dict") to nil and then test the code flow, you can try the following.

1. Put the breakpoint properly after initialised to the desired value.
2. then execute "expression dict = nil" in lldb command line to change it.    (for example "nil")
3. Step over the break point.
4. Check the variable "dict" in the next line. It will be nil.

It will look something like in the console.

```
(lldb) expression dict = nil
(NSDictionary *) $5 = nil
```

Answer (score 8):

If you are using Xcode 10 or 11 put the breakpoint properly after initialised to the required variable then you can change your variable using `po myString = "Hello World"` easily.

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like this to happen every-time the break point is hit you can add the expression to your breakpoint.

1. Create a breakpoint at the point you want to manipulate the variable
2. Right click and select edit breakpoint
3. In the action radio box select 'Debugger Command'
4. Type in `e yourStringName = "Your new value"`
5. Check the 'automatically continue after evaluating actions' checkbox.

[image: Screenshot of example breakpoint with expression command]