# How to change NSURL variable value while debugging with LLVM in XCode using expr command?

Tags: ios, lldb

In Xcode, LLDB could change variable value by expr command while debugging(see [How to change variables value while debugging with LLVM in XCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907387/how-to-change-variables-value-while-debugging-with-llvm-in-xcode)). I used this method to change a string value successfully, but when I change a NSURL variable to a new instance, I got an error:

```
(lldb) expr url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"www.example.com"];
error: no known method '+URLWithString:'; cast the message send to the method's return type
error: 1 errors parsing expression
```

How could I change url to a new value? Thanks.

Comment: Did you include `Foundation.framework` ?

Comment: Should be: `[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com"];` ?

Comment: @Shivan Raptor 
Yes, I have inlcuded `Fondation.framework`;
 `[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com"]` not work.
Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may try explicitly casting, i.e.

```
expr url = (NSURL *)[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.example.com"];
```

Because the LLDB sometimes cannot obtain the return type. For example,

```
// You should specify the return type here:
expr (int)[UIApplication version]

// instead of
expr [UIApplication version]
```

Answer (score 0):

for Swift 5:

```
expr url = URL(string:"https://www.example.com")!
```