# Modify object using lldb and XCode 4.5

Tags: xcode, xcode4.5, lldb

I have the following line of code

```
 CGAffineTransform rotate = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( 1.0 / 240.0 * 3.14 );
```

Is it possible to change rotate variable on the fly  and initialise it with `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( 1.0 / 180.0 * 10 )`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6351297/1671729) answer may help you, it did me.

Quote:

You can do this in the debug console. Say you have `NSString* myVar`. In the console, after (gdb), type `set myVar = @"My new string"`. If you are using (lldb), then use the equivalent expression `expr myVar = @"My new string"` instead.